# How to use appsettings in nunit dotnet core test project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nunit, appsettings

I've managed to add the AppSettings in my Api project from the `appsettings.json` file like this

Startup.cs in the `ConfigureServices()` function

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

Controller.cs

```
private readonly AppSettings _AppSettings;

public UserProfilesController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
   _AppSettings = appSettings.Value;
}
```

But I have no idea how to do this for my test project. I have no `Startup.ts` in my test project. So how can I add the appsettings the same way in my test project?

EDIT:

One nunit test

```
    [Test]
    public void Post_Should_Create_A_Single_UserProfile()
    {
        // Arrange
        var profile = Dummy.GenerateCreateUserProfileDto();

        MyMvc
        .Controller<UserProfilesController>()
        .Calling(c => c.Post(profile))
        .ShouldReturn()
        .Ok()
        .WithResponseModelOfType<UserProfileDto>()
        .Passing(target =>
        {
            target.Should().NotBeNull(because: "a record is expected here");
            target.Id.Should().BeGreaterThan(0, because: "a id is expected");
            target.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(profile, opt => opt
                .Excluding(c => c.Id)
                .Excluding(c => c.CreatedOn)
                .Excluding(c => c.ModifiedOn),
                because: "the record returned is expected to be the same as the record inserted");

            // Clean up
            _Repo.Delete(target.Id);
        });
    }
```

My post function

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CreateUserProfileDto profile)
    {
        using (var fileManager = new FileManager())
        using (var manager = new UserProfilesRepository())
        {
            var mapped = Mapper.Map<UserProfile>(profile);
            // Only save the profile image if one is selected
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.Image))
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = fileManager.SaveProfileImage(
                        profile.Image,
                        _AppSettings.Profile.AbsolutePath,
                        _AppSettings.BaseUrl,
                        _AppSettings.Profile.RelativePath
                    );
                    mapped.FilePath = result.AbsolutePath;
                    mapped.ProfilePicture = result.RelativePath;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500);
                }
            }

            manager.Save(mapped);

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<UserProfileDto>(mapped));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code for the unit test. You could just as easily mock the IOptions interface in your unit tests.

Comment: @Nkosi I've posted one of the nunit tests and the post code on the controller that uses the appsettings.

Comment: are you using this Nunit as part of your application or is it a different project?

Comment: Its a different project in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is an artefact of using the MyTested mocking framework. It creates a controller with mock values for the controller's dependencies (the `IOptions<AppSettings>` instance). This mock will return default (null) values for any property that hasn't been specifically configured.

If this is a unit test, you actually don't want to test this by loading from the appsettings using `ConfigurationBuilder` etc. Instead, you should provide the `AppSettings` object as a dependency in your test, with explicitly defined values.

**MyTested.AspNetCore.Mvc**

```
using MyTested.AspNetCore.Mvc.DependencyInjection;

[Test]
public void Post_Should_Create_A_Single_UserProfile()
{
    // Arrange
    var profile = Dummy.GenerateCreateUserProfileDto();

    MyMvc
    .Controller<UserProfilesController>()
    .WithOptions(options => options
        .For<AppSettings>(settings => settings.Cache = true))
    .Calling(c => c.Post(profile))
    .ShouldReturn()
    .Ok()
}
```

**Original Answer : MyTested.WebApi**

For example, you might do something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

[Test]
public void Post_Should_Create_A_Single_UserProfile()
{
    // Arrange
    var profile = Dummy.GenerateCreateUserProfileDto();
    var mockedSettings = new AppSettings
    {
         MyValue = "the test value"
    }

    MyMvc
    .Controller<UserProfilesController>()
    .WithResolvedDependencyFor<IOptions<AppSettings>>(Options.Create(mockedSettings))
    .Calling(c => c.Post(profile))
    .ShouldReturn()
    .Ok()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is much appreciated! I cant seem to use `WithResolvedDependencyFor` though. I'm getting First guess a missing dependency? Can I ask your assistance again? `'IControllerBuilder<UserProfilesController>' does not contain a definition for 'WithResolvedDependencyFor' and no extension method 'WithResolvedDependencyFor' accepting a first argument of type 'IControllerBuilder<UserProfilesController>'`

Comment: Ah - you linked to the wrong version before, I'll update my answer

Comment: Sorry for linking the wrong version! With your help I managed to get the AppSettings working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You're mocking your MVC Controller to test it. This way, you should create your `UserProfilesController` passing a mocked `appSettings` object.

Another option is to start the application to test it using the `Startup.cs` class.
I've never used nUnit, but in xUnit I configure my test project like this:

```
TestServer testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("Development").UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Since I'm using `Development` environment, I also need a `appsettings.Development.json` file in my test project.

Then, you can use the in-memmory server that you created like this:

```
testServer.CreateClient().PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
```

EDIT:

The TestServer is from Microsoft package:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0"
```

So, it should work fine with nUnit.